Movie that uses USB-Holo Table interface?
I'm trying to remember all the uses of Quantum of Solace 'Holo Tables' (alá Pixelsense) in recent movies, and there is one example that (whilst I can recall the imagery) I can't locate what movie it's from?
The USB pen/data recorder is simply placed on the table, without any need for connection/transfer and the table surface immediately retrieves the information off it and interfaces it in a useful way.

I believe the data taken off the devices is images/photographs
The device is not a Mobile phone
The table creates an outline of the device when it is placed down.

Does anyone know what Movie/TV show this is from? and if so, could you provide screenshots to confirm?
It's not the devices from: Quantum of Solace, Mission Impossible:Ghost Protocol, Iron-Man, The Avengers or Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D

I believe there's such a device in Ghostrider 2. But I think that was map and not really a table.

I am still thinking the outline of the device is from Ghost Protocol. While I'm not positive of a Ghost Protocol connection, I do remember the exact scene you are talking about in a movie. Wish I had that Eidetic recall to help here!

It definitely isn't Ghost Protocol I'm thinking of, hence its inclusion in the list...

I could swear I saw a scene like this in CSI Miami or one of the CSI shows.

Could you provide a timeframe, male/female protagonist, movie/TV genre?

I have not watched the movie in a while, so I cannot confirm the table with the outline of a device portion, but the Pixelsense concept (Renamed from Surface after Microsoft came out with the tablet named surface) theoretically was the inspiration for the interfaces in the movie Minority Report with Tom Cruise.
Director Steven Spielberg has supposedly admitted that the concept for the Minority Report display interface came about from talks with Microsoft during the making of the movie (However, I can only find one blog stating this).

i think i saw something like this in amazing spider-man 1 when peter submitted something for oscorp using a usb, if i'm not mistaken...but maybe i saw it from different movie

Did you already have a chance to confirm or deny the given answers, yet?

nope, sorry. still waiting on this one.

I think I've seen this being done in the rebooted Hawaii 5-0. Some impressions of the set can be seen in this YouTube clip. Unfortunately I haven't found a shot of the actual scene. They place a camera or some drive on the table and it's read in some way though. This page has a shot of the table as seen in the show, although there's no accessed device on it.

That is a Pixelsense (aka Surface Table), and not the one I remember (having never watched the show!) Nice try though.

Could you try to describe the table then? Is the whole table a display? Or is there a border? Are there many color or is it more or less "monochrome"? (Don't answer as a comment, add it to your question.) My first thought has been 5-0 or one of the CSI series? Any chance it's been one of those?

Everything I recall I've already put in my question I'm afraid..

Minority Report had one, I think.

Ok, since you already ruled out pretty much, I'm gonna ask, could it actually have just been a trailer where you saw that? Some trailers for The Amazing Spider-Man 2: Rise of Electro feature exactly such a scene, where there's a touch table that automatically connects to some device (neither a phone, nor really a usual USB stick), marks its outlines and takes some photos from it that are then shuffled around.






And while the final movie didn't get released until 3 months after you asked your question, the trailers have been available as early as the start of December 2013 at least (as the 2nd of the above YouTube videos shows). So you might just have seen this in a trailer, which is why you might have had difficulties to pin it to an actual movie. Furthermore, this particular scene about Oscorp tracking Peter

 wasn't actually in the final film.

So when seeing the full movie later, you didn't realize it either.

Interestingly enough I got reminded of this question and this movie while watching the corresponding scene in Ghost Protocol.
